# MERGE statement never getting a MATCH

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to SQL and am trying to alter some existing code that I inherited. I apologize for the lengthy code but I'm including everything as I'm not sure what's important. In a nutshell, I'm trying to update the output of a stored procedure (of which this is the last bit) to include 4 new fields. I've confirmed that #TotalDocSales contains the new fields, but this merge fails to add it to #PromoDiscountSales. I've visually inspected both tables and can confirm that the data in the ON section should produce a match. I added the CONVERT functions to the SELECT statement in order to bring the data types of both tables into complete alignment. (I don't know if this was necessary but it seemed like a place to start.)

```
MERGE INTO #PromoDiscountSales AS T
USING (
        SELECT  CONVERT(date, Dttransdate) AS DtTransDate, 
                r.WeekENDing, 
                r.MonthName, 
                r.MonthPeriod, 
                r.FYE, 
                CONVERT(varchar(12), DocNumber) As DocNumber, 
                CONVERT(varchar(5), DocType) AS DocType,  
                CONVERT(int, LocationNum) AS LocationNum, 
                l.LocationNumName, 
                l.Region, 
                StoreType, 
                CONVERT(varchar(25), ItemNum) AS ItemNum, 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(Description)) As ItemDescription, 
                PromoItemNum, 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(PromoItemDesc)) AS PromoItemDescription, 
                CONVERT(int, VendorNum) AS VendorNum, 
                VendorName ,
                CONVERT(int, DepartmentNum) As DepartmentNum, 
                CONVERT(varchar(25), ItemGroup) AS ItemGroup,
                CONVERT(varchar(25), PromoAppliedOn) AS PromoAppliedOn, 
                CONVERT(varchar(200), PromoAppliedOnVendor) AS PromoAppliedOnVendor, 
                TotalSales, 
                COGS, 
                QtySold, 
                DiscountAmt as DiscountAmount, 
                TotalSalesAfterDisc as NetTotalSales, 
                NoOfPromoQty, 
                RetailPrice, 
                PromoSalesPrice, 
                GrossSales,
                RedTagItemCode,
                VendorsItemNum,
                PosSlsprsnNum1,
                PosSlsprsnNum2,
                PosSlsprsnNum3

        FROM   #TotalDocSales t
        JOIN C_PRODUCTION.dbo.TU_MD_RETAILCALENDAR r with (nolock) 
            ON t.DtTransDate = r.Date
        JOIN C_PRODUCTION.dbo.TU_MD_LOCATION l with (nolock) 
            ON t.LocationNum = l.LocNum
        WHERE  (TotalSales <> 0 
                OR COGS <> 0 
                OR QtySold <> 0 
                OR QtySold <> 0 
                OR TotalSalesAfterDisc <> 0 
                OR RetailPrice <> 0 
                OR PromoSalesPrice <> 0 
                OR GrossSales <> 0)

) AS S
ON T.DtTransDate = S.DtTransDate 
   AND .LocationNum = S.LocationNum 
   AND T.DocNumber = S.DocNumber 
   AND T.DocType = S.DocType 
   AND LTRIM(RTRIM(T.ItemNum)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(S.ItemNum)) 
   AND T.VendorNum  = S.VendorNum  
   AND LTRIM(RTRIM(T.ItemGroup)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(S.ItemGroup)) 
   AND T.DepartmentNum = S.DepartmentNum
   AND LTRIM(RTRIM(T.PromoAppliedOn)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(S.PromoAppliedOn))
   AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(T.PromoAppliedOnVendor,''))) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(S.PromoAppliedOnVendor,'')))

WHEN  MATCHED 
        
THEN UPDATE
SET 
    VendorsItemNum = S.VendorsItemNum,
    PosSlsprsnNum1 = S.PosSlsprsnNum1,
    PosSlsprsnNum2 = S.PosSlsprsnNum2,
    PosSlsprsnNum3 = S.PosSlsprsnNum3,
    UpdatedDate = GETDATE()

WHEN  NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT

    (   DtTransDate, 
        WeekENDing, 
        MonthName, 
        MonthPeriod, 
        FYE, 
        DocNumber, 
        DocType, 
        LocationNum, 
        LocationNumName, 
        Region, 
        StoreType, 
        ItemNum, 
        RedTagItemCode,
        ItemDescription, 
        PromoItemNum, 
        PromoItemDescription, 
        VendorNum , 
        VendorName , 
        DepartmentNum, 
        ItemGroup, 
        PromoAppliedOn, 
        PromoAppliedOnVENDor, 
        TotalSales, 
        COGS, 
        QtySold, 
        RetailPrice, 
        PromoSalesPrice, 
        DiscountAmount, 
        NetTotalSales, 
        NoOfPromoQty, 
        GrossSales, 
        VendorsItemNum,
        PosSlsprsnNum1,
        PosSlsprsnNum2,
        PosSlsprsnNum3,
        LoadedDate)

    VALUES (
        S.DtTransDate, 
        S.WeekENDing, 
        S.MonthName, 
        S.MonthPeriod, 
        s.FYE, 
        s.DocNumber, 
        s.DocType, 
        s.LocationNum, 
        s.LocationNumName, 
        s.Region, 
        s.StoreType, 
        s.ItemNum, 
        s.RedTagItemCode,
        s.ItemDescription, 
        s.PromoItemNum, 
        s.PromoItemDescription, 
        s.VendorNum , 
        s.VendorName ,
        s.DepartmentNum, 
        s.ItemGroup, 
        s.PromoAppliedOn, 
        s.PromoAppliedOnVENDor, 
        s.TotalSales, 
        s.COGS, 
        s.QtySold, 
        s.RetailPrice,
        s.PromoSalesPrice, 
        s.DiscountAmount, 
        s.NetTotalSales, 
        s.NoOfPromoQty,
        s.GrossSales, 
        s.VendorsItemNum,
        s.PosSlsprsnNum1,
        s.PosSlsprsnNum2,
        s.PosSlsprsnNum3,   
        GETDATE());
```

Comment: You should have and clause between the condition @jaydubs

Comment: thank you Prakhar. the ANDs were in the original code but I accidentally deleted them when I posted here. They've been added in.

Comment: I would start off by converting the merge statement into an inner join between the two data sets and if you don't get results then start commenting out the join conditions until data is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ross. I did that and the inner join worked perfectly.

Comment: @jaydubs - Question, what values do you see in #PromoDiscountSales .PosSlsprsnNum1-3 after the merge statement runs, nulls and you are sure they are the same records that were matched  in the merge?

Comment: I see zeroes. To the best of my knowledge they are the same records. The data looks exactly the same.

Comment: Hi Ross. I wanted to let you know that I was able to resolve this problem. You pointed me in the right direction. One of my data types was an incorrectly sized varchar and that's what was stopping the merge.

Answer (score 1):

The VendorsItemNum **datatype** was `varchar(16)` in **#PromoDiscountSales** but `varchar(25)` in  **#TotalDocSales**, so when the merge got to this assignment: `VendorsItemNum = S.VendorsItemNum` it stopped.

Once I changed the **VendorsItemNum** datatype to `varchar(25)` in **#PromoDiscountSales** the merge could proceed.